# laravel 5.4 Mailable implements ShouldQueue don't sent email

Tags: php, email, laravel-5.4

This work fine and the email is sent to `log(MAIL_DRIVER=log)` and `mailtrap.io(MAIL_DRIVER=smtp)` succesfully

```
            class VerificationNewAccount extends Mailable
            {
                use Queueable, SerializesModels;
                public function __construct()
                {
                }
                public function build()
                {
                    return $this->from('noreply@example.com')
                        ->view('email.verification-request');
                }
            }
            // in controller
            Mail::to('test@gmail.com')->send(new VerificationNewAccount());
```

When i implement ShouldQueue the email is printed in `log(MAIL_DRIVER=log)` but when i try to send to `mailtrap.io(MAIL_DRIVER=smtp)` the email never is sent

```
            // running the queue in terminal
            php artisan queue:work --queue
```

then the class implements ShouldQueue

```
            class VerificationNewAccount extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
            {
                use Queueable, SerializesModels;
                public function __construct()
                {
                }
                public function build()
                {
                    return $this->from('noreply@example.com')
                        ->view('email.verification-request');
                }
            }
            // in controller
            Mail::to('test@gmail.com')->send(new VerificationNewAccount());
```

There is no error printed in laravel.log file. i don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after many test this is how i solved the problem.

Dont use `ShouldQueue`

```
            class VerificationNewAccount extends Mailable
            {
                use Queueable, SerializesModels;
                public function __construct()
                {
                }
                public function build()
                {
                    return $this->from('noreply@example.com')
                        ->view('email.verification-request');
                }
            }
```

Instead use the basis `->queue`

```
            Mail::to('test@gmail.com')->queue(new VerificationNewAccount($ran));
```

now the email is sent to `gmail`

The weird part is that now the email is not printed in `log`. 
Well i dont care. It woks!